# Split string in three parts by character length c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, clob

I've got a question about splitting a string message in three parts depending on the length of characters. The reason is because my stored procedure won't take more than 32767 characters. (pl/sql payload) Therefore i would like to send three messages (three clobs) to the stored procedure which can append those messages and send it to a queue.

Which solution is the best if I've got a `string message` and I need to calculate it into three parts where the max length of the message can be 32.000 characters?

What the stored procedure need: `(qname IN varchar2, i_clob1 IN clob, i_clob2 IN clob, i_clob3 IN clob)`

And how to send it in three parts if the `string message` is less than 32.000 characters for the first part but I want to send it in three parts anyway?

Here is my code which take one message (i_clob).

```
 public void Enqueue(string queueName, string mess)
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = null;
            try
            {
                cmd = new OracleCommand("", m_Connection)
                    {
                        CommandText = m_InSpName,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };


                //add Aq queue name 
                OracleParameter qName = new OracleParameter("qname", OracleType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        Value = queueName
                    };

                //add message to enqueue
                OracleParameter message = new OracleParameter("i_clob", OracleType.Clob)
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    };
                mess = mess.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");
                message.Value = mess;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(qName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(message);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //rethrow exception and make sure we clean up i.e. execute finally below
                throw new Exception("An error occurred trying to deliver the message to the queue", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @varocarbas yes devide into 3 strings. And if the character count is lower than 32000 characters it still need to devide it into 3 strings because the storage procedure need all three conditions

Comment: Yes, clear. I deleted my question because I re-read your post and my doubt was clarified. There you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you are looking for something on these lines:

```
string i_clob1 = "";
string i_clob2 = "";
string i_clob3 = "";
if (message.Length >= 3 && message.Length <= 32000 * 3)
{
    int lastStart = 2 * message.Length / 3;
    int lastLength = message.Length - lastStart;
    i_clob1 = message.Substring(0, message.Length / 3);
    i_clob2 = message.Substring(message.Length / 3, message.Length / 3);
    i_clob3 = message.Substring(lastStart, lastLength);
}
else if (message.Length < 3)
{
    i_clob1 = message;
}
```

Comment: Hi @varocarbas. I came across a problem with your solution yesterday. Because im using this for a xml doc. The "cut" can appear in the xml where there can be a "field name"  like `<description></description>` which will cause problems when sending it further to the procedure. Therefore i need to cut it by a specific field name three times. I have a specific xml doc so it should'nt cause any problems.

Comment: @Petey This solution delivers an excellent result under the conditions you proposed, that is: dividing into three parts by making sure that its length is below certain value. The usual proceeding to split by a string/character is using Split; but this is a completely different problem. This solution didn't stop working; but your problem has changed isn't it?

Comment: @Petey also I am not sure about the exact requirements. If you explain me a bit better what you want, I might adapt my code (in case of  being straightforward; otherwise, you know that you have to ask a new answer). An example always helps. As an introduction: you can use Split to get parts from strings but you would not have any control on the size; if you rely on an approach on the lines the one I proposed, you wouldn't have any control on the contents; if you want both things, you would have to come up with a mixture of both which is not straightforward (= new question).

Comment: You are right. It is working but I came across a new problem when testing some xml transfers. I still need to be below the same length in each i_clob but by splitting it with a exact field name, so it won't cut the message in the actual fieldname i provide. :-)

Comment: I will try edit my question here, so you and others can understand the situation more specifically :)

Comment: @Petey see this problem. Imagine that you don't want to cut "this string"; and that the first chunk has a length of 32000 (the limit) and cuts the string. First chunk = ".... this" and Second Chunk = "string..." -> this situation which I understand that can happen might be problematic.

Comment: @Petey the best way to get attention is posting a new question. You can send me a message once it is done such that I can take a look at it. Nobody will care about a so old question and I will be willing to help you in case of having to do a very slight modification (re-doing a question appreciably goes against SO rules and against what is much more important: what I am willing to accept :))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic String Splitter:

```
private IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string incomingString, int numberToCut)
    {
        int nombreDeCaractere = incomingString.Length;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string temp = string.Empty;
        int curseur = 0;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberToCut - 1; i++)
            {
                temp += incomingString.Substring(i + curseur, 1);
            }

            result.Add(temp);
            temp = string.Empty;
            curseur += numberToCut;
        } while (nombreDeCaractere >= curseur + numberToCut);

        temp = string.Empty;
        for (int i = curseur; i < nombreDeCaractere; i++)
        {
            temp += incomingString.Substring(i, 1);
        }

        result.Add(temp);

        return result;
    }
```